# Compare two SQL date columns. If account is over a year old add to a calculated column that it is old, or else add to the calc column it is new

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a computed column for testing if a contact in my database is over one year old.

Right now I created a quick test table with id as an int, and DateCreated as a datetime. I can create the date plus 1 year and the current date but I don't know how to compare these values and return the following strings.

If the account is older than 1 year, it must say "House Account"
If the account is less than 1 year it must say "New Account"

This is what I got so far. How on Earth would you do this sort of thing?

```
declare @AccountType datetime

select 
   id
  ,DateCreated
  ,DATEADD(year,1,DateCreated) as 'DatePlus1Yr'
  ,GETDATE() as 'CurrentDate'

FROM 
  Test
```

Comment: Using `GetDate()` within a query is chasing a moving target, impacts performance, and may produce curious results, e.g. as the date changes.  It is almost always a better idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and then use that value as needed.  This is more important across multiple statements as in a stored procedure.  The most common reason to use `GetDate()` multiple times is when capturing the start and end times for a long running operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, DateCreated,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DateCreated) < 365 THEN 'New Account'
            ELSE 'House Account'
       END AS AccountType
    FROM Test;
```